# How can I check month and day order in mixed date format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

There's column which contains date in different formats (ie. `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-DD-MM`).

When I query it with format time:date, it throw an error: date/time field value out of range: "2022-23-02"

How can i solve it?

How can I check if it's YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-DD-MM or another?

Comment: What date would be "2022-02-03" and what about "2022-04-02" ? February, March or April? How would you know?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no field that tells you whether it's YYYY-DD-MM or YYYY-MM-DD, you are kinda out of luck because it's possible that a value could be valid in both formats.

If you are able to redesign, and you must store the date as a string then use YYYY-MM-DD as it's easier for sorting. Optimally, just pass a JavaScript Date object to field of type `date`, `timestamp`, or `timestampz` to the database driver or orm and let it handle the conversion for you. Here's an example with node-postgres: https://node-postgres.com/features/types (the section labeled "date / timestamp / timestamptz")